# Setting up Windows Service bus 1.1 Management Portal

Tags: azure, servicebus

I am trying to set up Windows Service bus 1.1 on my development machine(Windows7). I configured a farm on my local machine and enabled management of Management portal while configuring the farm

I am not able to see a management portal when I browse to https:// after entering my credentials I am just getting a XML description of my farm but not any UI .

I am not sure what am I missing and  the documentation does not cover anything about setting up management portal.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you only installed Windows Service Bus 1.1, you are not going to be able to use the management portal. It is a Windows Azure feature.

It is possible to get a similar management experience similar to the cloud by using Service Bus integration by installing **Windows Azure Pack** but it is only available for Windows Server, so the only option for your management operations on Windows 7 are PowerShell commands.

Comment: Looks like that is the only approach and unfortunately I would need windows server 2012 to install Windows Azure Pack. Not possible to use it on win 7

Comment: Then you have to do the management operations with PowerShell commands, that's the only way as describe here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282142.aspx) _Service Bus runtime only (standalone): In this deployment scenario, there is a single administrator who deploys and manages the Service Bus farm, and creates namespaces. All management operations are supported with PowerShell commands, and there is no user interface (with the exception of the Service Bus configuration wizard for initial configuration)._